# Como puedo utilizar el login de Google en Wordpress (Sin plugins de terceros)?

Tags: wordpress, google-oauth, autenticacion

Tengo unas paginas con información privada.

Solo tengo opción de utilizar javascript del lado del cliente, o PHP del lado del servidor
pero solo por medio de un plugin (haciendo un plugin con el codigo que necesito), no tengo acceso al servidor directamente. Ademas, me interesa tener separado el login de Wordpress. No me sirve utilizar plugins de terceros.

Me interesa que el usuario pueda iniciar sesión con una cuenta corporativa de Google (correo@empresa.com) y ya que tenga su sesión iniciada, pueda ver el contenido de esas paginas.

Estoy usando la documentación de Google (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) pero no se como puedo hacerle para ocultar y mostrar el contenido, sin tener que redireccionar cada vez que el usuario cambia o recarga la pagina (debido a que cada que entra a la pagina, se realiza la comprobación).
Tampoco puedo realizar la comprobación del lado del cliente porque sabemos que no es confiable.

Gracias

Comment: Si tienes acceso a la web haz una copia con un plugin y trabaja en local, crea un custom field que agregue un checkbox en el fronted, luego antes de cargar la pagina revisa si el checkbox es true, si es asi cambiar el template por default por el tuyo, ahi haces la comprobación por medio de un token, si es correcto lo muestras, cabe recalcar que todo es posible desde un plugin propio sin necesidad de acceder al codigo fuente del sitio pero si que necesitas cierto nivel desarrollando plugins y conociendo el core.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Muchas gracias @JefferzonBol No lo habia pensado de esa forma, me sirve mucho.